# Java method that accepts two strings as arguments and returns the first string with all instances of the second string removed

Tags: bluej

I need to create a method that, as the title says, accepts two strings as arguments, takes the first string, and removes any letters that are in the second string.

ex. ("How are you doing today" , "hey")

would return "ow ar ou doing toda"

I have this

```
    while(counter < length){
        String letter = phrase.substring(counter, counter+1);
        if(!letter.equals(second)){
            filtered = filtered + letter;
        }
        counter++;
    }
```

Which works if it is only a single letter.  I cannot figure out how to make it work using multiple letters in the second string.

I can't use replace or arrays.

Comment: The [`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) method would be quite helpful to you here.

Comment: You could convert the Strings into Char arrays and then do a double iteration, not to far from what you've tried already.

Comment: I cannot see why u cannot use Arrays with "intersections", but if you say this code is working for you, why do not you just put it in another loop?

Answer (score 1):

Here's pseudo-code for one way to do it:

```
assign 1:st string to resultString

for each letter in 2:nd string
    delete instances of that letter in resultString
    by means of methods indexOf, substring and contains
```

Answer (score 1):

Here´s something you could use (there might be other ways):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(customStr("How are you doing today", "hey"));
}

public static String customStr(final String base, final String remove){
    String baseCopy = base.trim();
    String removeCopy = remove.trim();

    // Delete all uppercase & lowercase letters using a regex [HEYhey]
    baseCopy = base.replaceAll("[" + removeCopy.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH) 
            + removeCopy.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH) + "]", "");

    return baseCopy;
}
```

Output is

> ow ar ou doing toda